# "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" moviepy error

Tags: python, moviepy

I am using the **MoviePy** library to automatically concatenate videos there are in an folder. But when I run this code:

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *
clips = ['clips/clip-1.mp4', 'clips/clip-2.mp4']
video = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
```

I get this message in my terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/video machine/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    clips.append(VideoFileClip('clips/' + filename))
  File "C:\Users\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcg45UBcFon37-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 82, in __init__
    nbytes = audio_nbytes)
  File "C:\Users\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcg45UBcFon37-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\AudioFileClip.py", line 63, in __init__
    buffersize=buffersize)
  File "C:\Users\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcg45UBcFon37-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.buffer_around(1)
  File "C:\Users\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcg45UBcFon37-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 234, in buffer_around
    self.buffer =  self.read_chunk(self.buffersize)
  File "C:\Users\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcg45UBcFon37-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\readers.py", line 123, in read_chunk
    self.nchannels))
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug, but it was fixed in the latest version. You can see [TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/376) in details.

you can get the latest version of moviepy by running

```
pip3 install moviepy --upgrade
```